# Wrong consistency when making "after eight" chocolate

Tags: chocolate, mint

I am following a very simple recipe for making peppermint-stuffed chocolate, like the "[After Eight](http://data1.whicdn.com/images/5899028/original.jpg)" kind. I have a problem with the uniformity of the mint mass and am looking for advice.

A few spoons of egg white is hand-mixed with 60 g flormelis ([icing sugar](https://www.google.dk/search?q=flormelis&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=971&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=VLZfVZrKFcaQsgG2gIOQBg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=icing%20sugar)). Then a few drops of peppermint extract is mixed in. That's it.

The texture tastes good but is very "corny". You can taste and feel the small icing sugar grains, as if it is not fully dissolved. It tastes very strongly of icing sugar and then the aftertaste is the perfect peppermint taste.

I am looking for a method or recipe to make a smooth version of mint filling for the chocolates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recipe requests are off-topic but I can solve your problem nonetheless:

After Eights are filled with soft [fondant](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fondant_icing), which is sugar, often glucose syrup and water boiled to the soft ball stage, then whiped. If you google "poured fondant" you should find enough recipes online.